# Declare collection of interface objects to produce and consume

Tags: java, collections, interface

Can I declare a collection of interface objects that can both produce and consume?

I have an interface:

```
public interface IData {
    … 
}
```

And a class that implements it

```
public class WristMonData implements IData{
    …
}
```

I would like to declare a list of objects that implement that interface to pass to a method.  I can’t seem to get the collection declaration correct.

```
IData works = new WristMonData();
List<IData> doesntWork = new ArrayList<WristMonData>(); //Incompatible types error
```

My understanding is I should not use `List<? extends IData>` or `List<? super IData>` because I need to both produce and consume the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare

```
List<IData> itWorks = new ArrayList<IData>();
```

Then you can add elements of kind `WristMonData` to the list

Comment: Simple solutions are so satisfying.  Thank you!

Comment: You can put elements of type `WristMonData` into the list, but you won't be able to get them out without an explicit cast. This defeats the purpose of generics.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO  I have to wait for enough time to elapse before it is allowable.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
List<WristMonData> doesWork = new ArrayList<WristMonData>();
```

This can be passed to a method with signature:

```
public void method(List<? extends IData> list)
```

You will not be able to add non-null elements to the list in the body of the method if you use `? extends`. A good workaround is to use a private generic helper method.

```
public void method(List<? extends IData> list) {
    helper(list);
}

private <T extends IData> void helper(List<T> list) {
    // You can use list as both a consumer and supplier of Ts here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The problem if I do this, is trying to add a `WristMonData` object to the `List<? extends IData> list`.

Comment: @user432209 You don't try to add a `WristMonData` to the `List<? extends IData>`. You try to add it to the `List<WristMonData>`. `List<? extends IData>` is only needed as the method argument.

Comment: I'm passing in `list` I want to add to this, AKA (`List<? extends IData> list`).   Perhaps I'm not following you.  Could you elaborate?  How do i use `list.add(<a WristMonData object here>)`?

Comment: @user432209 When you create the list you do `List<WristMonData> list = new ArrayList<ListMonData>()`. You will be able to add and get `WristMonData` objects from this list without casts. If you need to pass this list to a method which accepts a list of any type of `IData` the argument of the method needs to be `List<? extends IData>` or `List<T>` where `<T extends IData>` as in my `helper` example. The `T` form is necessary if you want to be able to both add and get elements from the list in the method body

Comment: Correction.  I'm still stumbling.  Could you add the syntax for list.add in your methods above?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to add to the list? A `WristMonData` or a `T`?

Comment: A `WristMonData`.  I had to cast it of type `(T)` in the list.add method inside `helper` for this to work.

Comment: Right, well if you want to add `WristMonData` objects to the List then it should not be a generic method. The method argument should be `List<WristMonData>`. I'm confused about why you mentioned `IData` at all. If the method only applies to `WristMonData` but not `IData` what has `IData` got to do with it?

Comment: In this case `public void method(...)` is an implementation of a different interface allowing one worker method to use multiple implementations of that other interface.

Comment: @user432209 I'm really sorry but I don't think I understand your question. If the method does `list.add(new WristMonData());` then it only applies to one implementation. I think you need to edit this question, or ask another one with a lot more details.